# how to obtain execution plan from a PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a code snippet like :

```
declare
    cursor c is select ....
begin
    for i in c loop
        update table t1 where ti.c1 = i.column ...
    end loop;
end;
```

I am wondering how to obtain an execution plan from the update statement since there is involved a condition between a column from a table and a column from cursor.

Can anyone give me a hint, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way might be to capture the plan while it's executing, by noting the `sql_id` and `sql_child_number` from v$session, and running

```
select plan_table_output
from   table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(sql_id, sql_child_number));
```

Alternatively, you can embed the call in the PL/SQL for testing purposes and have it output the plan using `dbms_output.put_line`. (The plan will be the same for every loop iteration, unless you want to check the actual row counts etc, so I have added an `exit;` statement to make it stop after one execution.)

```
declare
    cursor c is select * from departments;
begin
    for r in c loop
        update employees e set e.email = e.email
        where  e.department_id = r.department_id;
        
        for p in (
            select p.plan_table_output
            from   table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'ALLSTATS LAST')) p
        )
        loop
            dbms_output.put_line(p.plan_table_output);
        end loop;
        
        rollback;
        exit;
    end loop;
end;
```

Which in my 19c demo HR schema gives:

```
SQL_ID  b5xbwbu4kd3r4, child number 1
-------------------------------------
UPDATE EMPLOYEES E SET E.EMAIL = E.EMAIL WHERE E.DEPARTMENT_ID = :B1
 
Plan hash value: 4075606039
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name              | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT  |                   |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |
|   1 |  UPDATE           | EMPLOYEES         |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| EMP_DEPARTMENT_IX |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("E"."DEPARTMENT_ID"=:B1)
```

To get the actual row counts as displayed above you would need to

```
alter session set statistics_level = all;
```

or else include the `/*+ gather_plan_statistics */` hint in the update.

Answer (score 0):

That's just an ordinary `UPDATE` statement. As it is in a loop, it executes row-by-row (returned from the cursor) (it might, though, update multiple rows at once, depending on its (`UPDATE`'s) `WHERE` clause).

Therefore, you'd just "extract" it from the loop and explain it, alone, e.g. if it is

```
cursor c is
  select id, job from emp_2;
begin
  for i in c loop
    update emp e set e.job = i.job where e.id = i.id;
  end loop;
end;
```

Suppose one of rows returned by cursor has `id = 7369`, `job = CLERK`; then

```
explain plan for update emp e set e.job = 'CLERK' where e.id = 7369;

select * from plan_table;
```